# PHP inbox with reply query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently developing a private messaging system, as the system currently stands i am able to send and retrieve message but i have problems with retrieving replies to the message. i am trying to develop a youtube type inbox/comment system. i have 3 tables fk related, MESSAGES(id, sid, rid,subject, message, senttime) sid is id for loged in user, rid is id for reciever user ie profile_id.... M_REPLY(id, mid, uid, reply, senttime) mid is the foreign key for message id, uid is id of the user that has sent the reply, reply is the actual message... 
below is my PHP code that performs message retrieval

```
// Initialize the variables
$mail ="";
// Get list of Private Messages
$sql = "SELECT users.*, messages.* 
        FROM users, messages 
        WHERE messages.rid= '$log_id' 
        AND users.id = messages.sid 
        AND rdelete = '0' 
        ORDER BY senttime DESC" or die(mysqli_error);
$query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// Gather data about the Pm's
if ($numrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $avatar = $row['avatar'];
        $subject = $row['subject'];
        $uname = $row['username'];
        $message = $row['message'];
        $senttime = $row['senttime'];
        $pro_pic = '<img src="user/'.$uname.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$uname.'" align="left" width="50" height="50" style="border:#E5E5E5 thin solid; padding:2px;">';
        $mail .= '<div><a href="user_account.php?u='.$uname.'">'.$pro_pic.' '.$uname.'</a> | '.$subject.'</a></span> <div> '.$senttime.' <br /> '.$message.'<div>Replies here....</div></div></div>';
    }
} else {
    $mail = 'No messages';
}
```

then i echo $mail in my html to display that....
plus i would like to know how i can display the reply text box without having it display over and over in the loop... please help

Comment: In a few seconds, someone will copy-paste a huge comment about mysql_* and mysqli_* functions being deprecated and unsafe. I guarantee it.

Comment: @MightyPork Why? There's no `mysql_` anywhere.

Comment: yes. but please bare in mind this is not the final work, i will use prepared statements and also preg replace and use htmlentities to avoid any form of attacks and hacks

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know, but still - it gets pasted on almost everything. Everyone is eager to complain about that ;)

Comment: Sidenote: Use `die (mysqli_error($conx))` instead of `die(mysqli_error)`

Comment: oh yea thats in another file.. the mysql connection works just fine.. plus i used sessions and everything else works just fine... thanx @Fred-ii-

Comment: hahahaha i understand what you mean... thats very true though @MightyPork

Comment: Instead of having a separate table for replies, why not just consider replies messages themselves?  You could add another field in the messages table, *replyTo*, and if it's *NULL* then it's an original message, and if it's not, then it is a reply to a message (or a reply to a reply).  Your first query would pull all records `WHERE replyTo=NULL`, then on display of the message, you'd pull all records where `replyTo=mid`.  This would allow a thread-like view similar to gmail.

As for replies to replies, it'd get a little trickier, but nothing a little creative problem solving can't fix. :)

Comment: @Trick that sounds like a good idea.... Thanks man, i fix that up in the system and see how it works... if i have any problems i will get back to this thread.. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could be of some help.  If you run into problems implementing it or aren't sure what I meant post back here or email me *(trick.developer.at.gmail.com)^ if you need more in-depth help.  *(Side note: I've implemented this design in the past with quite successful results.)*.

Comment: i implemented it... but my reply list is only returning one reply message. with [CODE]SELECT * FROM users, messages WHERE messages.replyto = '$mid' AND users.id = messages.sid ORDER BY senttime DESC [CODE] i dont know what the problem is been trying to fix it for days on in